# Batch export WLD+PNG file to GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export, batch, world-file

I created some WLDs from some old GeoTIFFs
I then loaded some new PNGs into QGIS using the WLDs
This worked well, it automatically put the new PNGs in the location of the old geotiffs which is exactly what I wanted.

Now I want to export the new PNGs as geotiffs
But I would like to do this as a batc process rather then one by one.
Is this possible?

Comment: Gdal_translate is your friend

Comment: Most of the tools in QGIS, including those from GDAL and other providers, have a Run as batch process option button found at the bottom of the tool form.

Comment: When I try, Gdal_translate does not accept PNG's nor the WLD nor png.aux.xml files as input. The files are greyed out and I cannot select them.

Comment: Even if I toggle "Do not filter invalid features" it still will not allow the PNGs layers as input.